# Azure VMs high-availability setup for data disk or storage

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, high-availability

I'm currently looking into a high-availability approach for a file server within Azure in which I will need to be deploying VMs for. The data on the file server will be constantly changing. From what I read so far, I will need at least 2 VMs and grouping them together into a shared availability set along with creating a cloud service. Although this will address the application and server aspect, what about the storage and the data on them?

I understand that I can't attach a single disk to multiple VMs so I'm a bit lost on how to proceed with this. Any thoughts or ideas on how to move forward with this?

In short, I have a VM with direct data disk attached to it that I'm looking to provide high-availability in the event that the VM goes offline; either through an outage, host patching, hardware maintenance, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into Azure Blob Storage - don't worry about disks etc, just let the Azure fabric handle the data redundancy and scalability for you!

Here's an "all you need" [introduction to WIndows Azure Storage](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-):

Comment: Hi AdaTheDev, I'm not clear I follow with this. It seems that the only way that the "failover" server can access the data that were being captured on the primary server is to use the blob storage location directly using the access keys?